# Can I log to file all the responses made during running cypress test?

Tags: cypress

When I'm running cypress e2e tests, application makes XHR requests. How can I log all this requests and responses? I don't want to stub these requests. I with to get an artifact with all requests and responses made during test. Gitlab is used as CI.

Main test code looks like this. All these are user defined commands, interacting with the application. Interacting with the application causes different requests to be made (e.g. I click a button, this causes the request).

```
it('Log response to a file',function(){
      cy.request({
          method: 'GET',
          url: 'https://<site>/home/payments/currency/confirm/*',
          headers: {
              'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          },
          body: {},
      }).then((response)=>{
      const someResponse =  response.body;
      console.log("hhhh"+someResponse);
      cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testResponse.json', someResponse);
      cy.login(login_name, pass)
      cy.typeOTPpinpad(secret)
      cy.makePayment('Currency', 'amount')
      cy.typeToken(secret)
      cy.logout()
})
})
```

Here is how I tried to use regular expression to catch request (id is unique and I need to use regular expressions).

```
https://<mysite>/home/payments/<currency>/confirm/* - asterisk is payment id.
```

Comment: Do you want to log these request and response to some location as file ? Is that what you need ?

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I need.

Answer (score 2):

You could grab the `request` and `response` and write to a location as below. I have write the request and response  to `fixture` folder as below: Try the below and let me know

```
it('Log request to a file',function(){
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'url_here',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {},
        }).then((request)=>{
        const someRequest =  JSON.stringify(request);
        console.log("hhhh"+someRequest);
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testRequest.json', someRequest);
        })
    })
```

// The below is for response:

```
it('Log response to a file',function(){
        cy.request({
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'url_here',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: {},
        }).then((response)=>{
        const someResponse =  response.body;
        console.log("hhhh"+someResponse);
        cy.writeFile('cypress/fixtures/testResponse.json', someResponse);
        })
    })
```

Comment: Where should I add my test steps?

Or this is an example of a test just making one request? I need to log all requests and responses made during test. Is there a setting in Cypress to do this?

Comment: As per the above example, cypress will log the request and response only while running the above test.

Comment: I haven't find a general setting for that.

Comment: If I understand correctly, I can add my code after yours, and add url? Can I add regular expression as url?

Comment: Unable to tell until I see your test code, please post your test code and url reg pattern

Comment: This is the same sample solution that i have posted right, I was asking about your test code included along my solution, with url and all

Comment: Sorry, posted it to the question body.

Comment: What is happening now ? Is that logging a response ?

Comment: No. It is trying to make a request from cy.request and logs html response to file. Asterisk is ignored, so response code is always 404. It doesn't catch other responses.

Comment: I don't know the flow of your application, but I guess you need to get the `uniqueID` and attach to end of the url. When do you receive the uniqueID ? is that after login ?

Answer (score 0):

The testrunner has such information on board:
[[image: 1]]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that I run browser in a headless mode on CI server.

Comment: check, I can't help you with that one. I tried searching, but it doesn't give me a good solution.